# Scrollbar in app tab fanpage

Tags: facebook, scrollbar, fluid-layout, scrollbars

I have a problem with the tab scroll bars in my app.

The measures are corect.

> width: 810px height: "BLOG" Fluid.

The detail is that the web site was made as a Wordpress style blog, with some pages especially for this BLOG with scroll bar to be with very large size. And I've been studying about "Fluid".

developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/

How can I apply the tutorial on a website made in wordpress?

The link is this application -- note the tab "Blog" and see the scroll bars.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Teste-Pagina/302897009754706?sk=app_314182471998939

I noticed that it is only when the page height is very great that this occurs. Can you help me would be very grateful.

Here are some settings of the app:

http://impactum.com.br/images/config_developers2.png

Ps: doing the same procedure to put the HTML did not work.

I would be very grateful if you help me